# How do I call an array within an IIFE using a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, iife

I have an array that's inside an IIFE, then I have a `forEach` loop that iterates over those array items but I don't know how to then call the function using the forEach loop.

```js
//IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression
let pokemonRepository = (function () {

  //List of Pokemon Characters
  let pokemonList = [
    { name: "Pikachu", height: 1.04, type: 'electric' },
    { name: "Bulbasaur", height: 2.04, type: ['grass', 'poison'] },
    { name: "Squirtle", height: 1.08, type: 'water' },
    { name: "Beedrill", height: 3.03, type: ['bug', 'poison'] },
    { name: "Dragonite", height: 7.03, type: ['dragon', 'flying'] },
    { name: "Igglybuff", height: 1.01, type: ['Normal', 'Fairy'] },
  ]

  function add(pokemon) {
    pokemonList.push(pokemon);
  }

  function getAll() {
    return pokemonList;
  }

  return {
    add: add,
    getAll: getAll
  };
})();

// Test of return functions inside IIFE 
// console.log(pokemonRepository.getAll());
// pokemonRepository.add({ name: 'Sandstorm' });
// console.log(pokemonRepository.getAll()); // [ { name: 'Sandstorm' } ]


// forEach loop
pokemonList.forEach(function (pokemon) {
  if (pokemon.height >= 7) {
    document.write("<div class='card'>" + "<p>" + pokemon.name + " " + "(Height:" + " " + pokemon.height + ") - Wow! that is a big pokemon! " + "</p>" + "</div>");
  } else if (pokemon.height) {
    document.write("<div class='card'>" + "<p>" + pokemon.name + " " + "(Height:" + " " + pokemon.height + ")  " + "</p>" + "</div>")
  }
});
```

I can call the items in the console.log using;

```
console.log(pokemonRepository.getAll());
```

but I want to call the repository using the `forEach` loop in the DOM.

Comment: Why not `pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered yourself - `getAll` returns the array, so you need to call it:

```js
pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function (pokemon) {
  if (pokemon.height >= 7) {
    document.write("<div class='card'>" + "<p>" + pokemon.name + " " + "(Height:" + " " + pokemon.height + ") - Wow! that is a big pokemon! " + "</p>" + "</div>");
  } else if (pokemon.height) {
    document.write("<div class='card'>" + "<p>" + pokemon.name + " " + "(Height:" + " " + pokemon.height + ")  " + "</p>" + "</div>")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try `pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(<callback>);`

Comment: How does this substantially differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: The two answers are 46 secs apart @double-beep. I think when I was typing my answer the answer that got accepted got submitted.

Comment: What's the point of keeping it then?

Comment: Is it creating any issues?